# Convertir dp a pixels inversa en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Necesito convertir `dp` a `pixeles` y `pixeles` a `dp` en Java de Android.

Obtengo el ancho de la pantalla del dispositivo, me devueleve un valor `float` que está en `dp`

```
public static float getWidthDeviceDP(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
}
```

y quiero definir el tamaño mínimo de un `TextView` con el método

```
tv.setMinWidth(<pixel>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí está un ejemplo, sería cuestión que se lo agregues a lo que ya tienes:

**De dp a px**

```
  public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
        return px;
    }
```

**De px a dp**

```
public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```

Respuesta obtenida de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android).

Answer (score 1):

Lo apropiado sería obtener los valores exactos obteniendo un valor float:

Pixeles a Dp:

```
public static float pxToDp(final Context context, final float px) {
    return px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

Dp a Pixels:

```
public static float dpTopx(final Context context, final float dp) {
    return dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

Pero si lo que deseas es obtener un valor int sería de esta forma:

Pixeles a Dp:

```
public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

Dp a pixeles:

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto te pueda ayudar, explica muy bien cómo funcionan los dp y entenderlo bien a mi me ayudó mucho.

[¿Qué son y para qué sirven los DP en Android?](https://tyris-software.com/que-son-y-para-que-sirven-los-dp-en-android/)

Un saludo
Gastry

Comment: Te faltó algo en tu respuesta no? Un enlace? Una solución?

Comment: Si, gracias por avisar, un despiste.
Ya lo he puesto.